# Is this pandas code equivalent? Very quick

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Are the two lines of code equivalent to each other? To me the results seem the same, but I seen libraries use the second method, perhaps there is a reason why?

```
df['some_column']

df.loc[:, 'some_column']
```

Comment: Both are same @katiex7. Where have you seen the use? It might be context specific.

Comment: I seen it used like so
                                  df.loc[:,n] = df.loc[:,n].astype('category').cat.as_ordered()
                                  categories = df[n].cat.categories

Comment: He assigns categories as df[n].cat.categories instead of df.loc[:,n].cat.categories so I think they are indeed the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they're equivalent here, but the `.loc` and `.iloc` accessors lets you express indexing operations that would be otherwise ambiguous and could lead to it doing the "wrong" thing or would otherwise be confusing readers of your code